# Unable to Push view after pushing view first time via UIcollectionView Cell- UInavigationcontroller object changes

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, uicollectionview

I am able to push a new view via a external UIcollectoinViewcell via the TapDetected method.Once the view has been pushed and I return back to the UICollectionView grid, I am unable to tap and push another view. The TapDetected is called, but the **controller** object changes and thus the view is not pushed again, not until I scroll the UICollectionView once more. So I can push another view only until I scroll the UIcollectionview Grid. Any insight in solving this will be appreciated.

1. The **controller** is pass from the UIViewcontroller as the UIViewcontroleller.

```
 private bool TapGesture_ShouldReceiveTouch(UIGestureRecognizer recognizer, UITouch touch)
        {
            return true;
        }

        private void TapDetected()
        {
            var username = this.username.Text;      

       
            var profileViewController = new ProfileViewController(username);
            profileViewController.ModalPresentationStyle =           
            UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
            controller.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
            controller.NavigationController.PushViewController(profileViewController, true);
   
        }
```

Comment: How is the tap gesture recogniser set up? Where is this code? How do you set.  `controller`? You have a lot of modal set up but then you are pushing onto a navigation controller.

Comment: I solved the issue by blacking the code in the ViewDidAppear method. So everytime a user comes back to the main collection view from clicking on an image it will reload the collection view thus preventing a null on click.